# iOS Delete Button - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I was wondering where does one get access to iOS delete button. This is the button that Apple uses to close the iAd window, and for deleting iPhone apps from the home screen, and also the Twitter App uses it to delete the photo that you add to a tweet.  Do they just download this image somewhere or is there an option for it somewhere like for the info button, and the detail disclosure.

Thanks

I also found that Growl uses this icon along with Lion's Mission Control...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) to extract about any iOS artwork that is not public. Just search for *close* and you will find several close button png images.

Answer (score 4):

Apple doesn't make that image available, unfortunately.
This iPad template has the icon you want, though, in a PSD: http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ipad-gui-psd/

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually an image and the iOS Simulator displays it, it should be hidden somewhere inside the Simulator frameworks or support files.

Answer (score -2):

What, you mean the circle with an X in it? It's pretty easy to make your own, either in an image editor or just drawing it in code. I can guarantee you that's what the Twitter app did.

Comment: No, because the image that the OS uses isn't public. It may not even be the same resource used in Springboard and in the iAd window.

Comment: I can make my own I just was thinking that Apple might make that public.  It just easier to use what Apple already supplies - don't have to worry about the normal and 2x images.